# Cross-database queries with numbered database name

Tags: sql, database, cross-database

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to SQL Server 2005.  I have a database containing most of the stored procedures and tables (we'll call it 'GrandDatabase').  Each user has its own separate database named after the user's numbered ID.  So I have a database list as follows, for example:

GrandDatabase
100
101
102
...

I need to join tables across the GrandDatabase and a user's database.  I've read elsewhere that the following should work, when executed from GrandDatabase:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    GrandDatabase.User INNER JOIN
    100.dbo.UserInfo ON GrandDatabase.User.UserID = 100.dbo.UserInfo.UserID
```

This gives me a syntax error, complaining about the '.' right after the first reference to the 100 database.  I did a little tweaking and discovered that this code works fine when I use non-numbered databases (for instance, replacing the '100' above with 'User100').  Does anybody know how to make this work with numbered database names?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the numbers into square brackets and using aliases, e.g.:

```
SELECT    *
FROM    GrandDatabase.User 
INNER JOIN    [100].dbo.UserInfo u
   ON GrandDatabase.User.UserID = u.UserID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [100].dbo.UserInfo instead of just the 100.

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing the database name with brackets:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    GrandDatabase.User INNER JOIN
    [100].dbo.UserInfo ON GrandDatabase.User.UserID = [100].dbo.UserInfo.UserID
```